# A subset that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $V = \mathbb R^3$. Give an example of a subset U of V such that U is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but is not a subspace

**My attempt:**

I know that according to the criterion for something to be a subspace, the only criteria not fulfilled is that U doesn't contain the zero vector. However I do not know how this could be! I can't understand how a subset can be closed under multiplication and addition and not have a zero vector!

Comment: The only option is $\varnothing$. It is closed under addition and scalar multiplication (it is vacuously true), but not a subspace.

Comment: Ahhh! Should've thought about the empty set first! Thank you!